# SSL/TLS Certificate validation related issue when calling Web API method in C# Website

Tags: c#, validation, ssl-certificate, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I am facing an issue with consuming my locally hosted Web API from my web site. The API works perfectly via Swagger.

**The exceptions I got:**

"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

**Code:**
[image]

I am on Windows 10 with .Net Fx 4.8

**PS:** I do not want to bypass the validation using the following code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

I am guessing some sort of configuration change is what I need to do.

**Edit 1:**

Here's my Postman output:

[image]

Help Please :)

Comment: Why is your address started from `http://` instead of `https://`?

Comment: Try testing it on Postman once. It has options to enable/disable SSL and also allows to attach certificates if required. It might give you some lead.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski even Https gives me the same error

Comment: @HarryPotter Thanks for the tip. I am on it.

Comment: @HarryPotter Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

That it can be a Windows Update problem.

That update caused the problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4489899/windows-10-update-kb4489899

To fix it you need to do some steps:

- Uninstall all chain certificates "Root Certification Authorities
  Reliable" (Some certificates can't be excluded, ignore them)
- Reinstall the chain certificates from [here](http://redeicp.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/InstaladorCadeiaV2.exe)

I had the problem with some clients and that solve the problem.

I don't know if it will fix your especific problem, but I hope so.